# How to hide/unhide main window chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I hide/unhide the main window of the extension from javascript. I have a context menu item within chrome and would like that menu item to show new information within the Main window extension. The window that pops out from the Extension's Icon, top right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pragmatically open a `browserAction` popup with JavaScript. Your best option would be to use the [HTML Notification API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/).

Comment: The HTML Notification API is deprecated now, unfortunately. Looking like we're SOL

Comment: Chrome now has a [rich notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) which provides some basic customization and interactivity. Otherwise the standard text notifications still work.

Comment: Can't use any HTML in either of those, though, just to be clear!